# Will 64-bit application work as 32-bit, when i install 64-bit applications into 32-bit program files (x86)

Tags: program-files

I would like to ask if I install 64-bit program into Program Files (x86), will it still work as 64-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  A 64 bit application will always only run 64bit, no matter where it's installed.

However, this will be a non-standard install location for a 64bit program, so would not be something I'd recommend.  64 bit applications should typically be installed to `Program Files`, not `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to not have mess in applications installed. I wasn't used to install to default folders in Vista...